# how to play video from a webservice which returns video as chunks of data

Tags: ios5, xcode4.3

I need to play a video in iPad, which is to be retrive from a web service.
I can not directly give a url to MPMoviePlayerController to play the video.
I need to create a SOAP web request to get the video from a webservice.

This webservice returns the request video in a form of chuncks of data, each of some few KBs.

My question is, how can we play these chunks of data in the iPad.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using a WebView.

viewController.h

@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *enbededWebView;

viewController.m

```
NSString *vedioYoubeString=@"<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://yoururl pass here" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

//[[self.view addSubview:_enbededWebView]loadHTMLString:vedioYoubeString baseURL:nil];

[_enbededWebView loadHTMLString:vedioYoubeString baseURL:nil];
```